# Swift array sort alphabetically and in group order

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

i am trying to order an array alphabetically and by group name's

My list is:

```
Name: A
Group: cats

Name: B
Group: dogs

Name: C
Group: cats
```

I have done the alphabetical order ordered by Name and it's showing me the following order:

```
A
cats

B
dogs

C
cats
```

But i'm having a migraine trying to sort them by the group, ex:

```
A
cats

C
cats

B
dogs
```

What i tried so far for alphabetical order and groups order:

```
case alpha:
    results.sorted { $0.first_name < $1.first_name }
case grouped:
    results.sorted { $0.group_name == $1.group_name }
```

Comment: You need a single sort operation. In the closure, If the names are the same then compare by group otherwise compare by name

Comment: I have a segmented control where i can select the type of the sort, so it does not help me to make it in a single sort operation.

Comment: So you may need multiple, single sort operations based on the segmented control (and it helps if you put *all* of your goals in your question), but the way you have it now the first sort is overridden by the second sort. You need to consider both criteria in the one sort operation.

Comment: Your second sort closure isn't even valid as it doesn't perform a relative comparison

Comment: Ok, i edited my question now.

Comment: Is your `results` array a `var` that you'd like to sort in place, or is it a `let`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
struct Animal {
    let Name: String
    let Group: String
}

let a1 = Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats")
let a2 = Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs")
let a3 = Animal(Name: "C", Group: "cats")

let animals = [a3, a2, a1]

let result = animals.sorted(by: {$0.Group < $1.Group}).sorted(by: {$0.Group == $1.Group && $0.Name < $1.Name })
result  //Prints [{Name "A", Group "cats"}, {Name "C", Group "cats"}, {Name "B", Group "dogs"}]
```

`sorted` returns a new array (`result`) and doesn't sort the initial array (animals) in place.

Comment: My code actually does this on another array(a new one), the problem in my case was with a bad string key.. the above code works well

Comment: Glad I could be of help, have a nice Sunday!

Comment: Changing your `animals` to `let animals = [a1, a2, a3]`, I get `[SortGroups.Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"), SortGroups.Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"), SortGroups.Animal(Name: "C", Group: "cats")]`, seems your code does not sorting the array correctly.

Comment: Still wrong. Try adding `let a4 = Animal(Name: "D", Group: "dogs")` and `let animals = [a1, a2, a3, a4]`. Two element lexicographical order cannot be achieved with `$0.Group <= $1.Group && $0.Name < $1.Name`.

Comment: My output **[SortGroups.Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"), SortGroups.Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"), SortGroups.Animal(Name: "C", Group: "cats"), SortGroups.Animal(Name: "D", Group: "dogs")]** (Xcode 9.4.1).

Comment: @OOPer Having `animals = [a4, a3, a2, a1, a4]` the result is `[{Name "A", Group "cats"}, {Name "C", Group "cats"}, {Name "B", Group "dogs"}, {Name "D", Group "dogs"}, {Name "D", Group "dogs"}]` . It is sorted by Group then by Name.

Comment: Seems your `sort` needs specific order in your input. You usually do not call that as `sort`.

Comment: "*specific order in your input*" None that I can see.

Comment: @Carpsen90, then you have not taken enough time.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
results.sorted {($0.group_name, $0.first_name) < ($1.group_name, $1.first_name)}
```

Example:

```
struct Item {
    var first_name: String
    var group_name: String
}

let results = [
    Item(first_name: "A", group_name: "cats"),
    Item(first_name: "B", group_name: "dogs"),
    Item(first_name: "C", group_name: "cats")
]
let sortedResult = results.sorted {($0.group_name, $0.first_name) < ($1.group_name, $1.first_name)}
print(sortedResult)
//->[SortGroups.Item(first_name: "A", group_name: "cats"), SortGroups.Item(first_name: "C", group_name: "cats"), SortGroups.Item(first_name: "B", group_name: "dogs")]
```

---

An example where Carpsen90's current code fails.

```
struct Animal {
    let Name: String
    let Group: String
}

let animals = [
    Animal(Name: "B", Group: "rats"),
    Animal(Name: "C", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "E", Group: "cats"),
    Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"),
    Animal(Name: "C", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "E", Group: "cats"),
    Animal(Name: "A", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "D", Group: "cats"),
    Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"),
    Animal(Name: "B", Group: "cats"),
    Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "D", Group: "rats"),
    Animal(Name: "A", Group: "rats"),
    Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "D", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "A", Group: "dogs"),
    Animal(Name: "A", Group: "rats")
]

let result = animals.sorted(by: {$0.Group < $1.Group}).sorted(by: {$0.Group == $1.Group && $0.Name < $1.Name })
print("[\n  "+result.map {String(describing: $0)}.joined(separator: ",\n  ")+"\n]")
```

Output:

> ```
> [
>   Animal(Name: "E", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "C", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "C", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "D", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "E", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "D", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "rats"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "rats"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "rats"),
>   Animal(Name: "D", Group: "rats")
> ]
> ```

Using tuple comparison for the same input:

```
let result2 = animals.sorted {($0.Group, $0.Name) < ($1.Group, $1.Name)}
print("[\n  "+result2.map {String(describing: $0)}.joined(separator: ",\n  ")+"\n]")
```

Output:

> ```
> [
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "D", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "E", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "E", Group: "cats"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "C", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "C", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "D", Group: "dogs"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "rats"),
>   Animal(Name: "A", Group: "rats"),
>   Animal(Name: "B", Group: "rats"),
>   Animal(Name: "D", Group: "rats")
> ]
> ```

Comment: `($0.group_name, $0.first_name) < ($1.group_name, $1.first_name)` Is this `tuple < tuple`? Haven't seen that before.

Comment: @Fabian, Please check [SE-0015 Tuple comparison operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md).